Use PHP mail() function in docker installation with mailcatcher
I have set up a local development environment using docker compose. It consists of nginx, php-fpm, mariadb, and mailcatcher. Everything is working good, but I can't make the mail() function work.
This is my compose.yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./html:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - internal
    depends_on:
      - php    

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html
      - ./custom-php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom-php.ini
    environment:
      PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d      
    networks:
      - internal    

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.4    
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
      MYSQL_USER: dbuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: dbpassword
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - mariadb_jazdy_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - internal

  mailcatcher:
    image: sj26/mailcatcher
    ports:
      - "1080:1080"
      - "1025:1025"    

networks:
  internal:

volumes:
  mariadb_jazdy_data:

This is my Dockerfile
FROM php:7.4-fpm
RUN curl -sSLf \
        -o /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions \
        https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && \
    install-php-extensions mysqli

and this is my custom-php.ini
; Enable mysqli extension
extension=mysqli.so

[mail function]
SMTP=127.0.0.1
smtp_port=1025
sendmail_from=sender@example.com

I tried different configuration for the SMTP, including localhost, or mailcatcher. Without any success.
What am I missing here? I really would like to make this work as I literally spent hours of googling and asking chat gpt. Thanks.
I tried using different docker images, installing sendmail in Dockerfile (https://r.je/sendmail-php-docker), but nothing seems to be working.

SMTP and smtp_port are only used on Windows. The docs for sj26/mailcatcher tell you exactly how to configure a Linux environment. You'll either need the catchmail app in your php container, or you'll need to use a mail library like PHPMailer that can speak SMTP directly.

What Alex said. mail() just calls the local sendmail binary which is likely somewhere between "not installed" and "not configured" in the docker image. Mail libraries typically also ensure that the messages that you send are properly formatted, which is a lot of legwork that mail() does not do in the slightest.

@AlexHowansky thank you very much for your comment. It led me to the right answer which I posted below.

I'm gonna answer my own question with the correct solution where Alex Howansky led me to.
However, I've made some changes also to the original compose.yaml, where I forgot to add the network directive under mailcatcher. But later, I found out, it didn't have to be there, at all.
So these is the final configuration how I made it work.
compose.yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./html:/var/www/html    
    depends_on:
      - php    

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html
      - ./custom-php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom-php.ini
    environment:
      PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d          

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.4    
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
      MYSQL_USER: dbuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: dbpassword
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - mariadb_jazdy_data:/var/lib/mysql    

  mailcatcher:
    image: sj26/mailcatcher
    ports:
      - "1080:1080"          

volumes:
  mariadb_jazdy_data:

Dockerfile
FROM php:7.4-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential software-properties-common
RUN apt-get install -y libsqlite3-dev ruby-dev
RUN gem install mailcatcher
RUN curl -sSLf \
        -o /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions \
        https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && \
    install-php-extensions mysqli
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

custom-ini.php
; Enable mysqli extension
extension=mysqli.so

[mail function]
sendmail_path=/usr/bin/env catchmail --smtp-ip mailcatcher --smtp-port 1025


glad you got it working, I would still suggest to look into a mailer library (like phpmailer already suggested) so you can talk natively to smtp, and also will help immensely if you need to send html formatted emails

Yes, that would be the next step. My goal here was to make it work, so that I can show my students how to work with the native mail() function
